# How do I connect to a bluetooth device from the Linux Kernel?

Tags: bluetooth, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am just starting to delve into the Linux kernel. As a starting point I am attempting to write a driver for an independent device (Mindstorms NXT. Yes, I know there are userspace alternatives, but that is not what I am looking for.) that may be connected to the host either by USB or Bluetooth. The aim is to expose a common interface as a character device, independent of the underlying connection.

The USB portion is up and running, but I am having a hard time figuring out how to scan and connect to a Bluetooth device from my module.

I am familiar with how to do this from user code, but I want to know how it may be done from the kernel.

Thus, my questions are as follows.

1. How do I scan for and connect to a remote Bluetooth device inside a kernel module?
2. Can I register a callback to be called whenever a Bluetooth device matching a given PID:HID/BTADDR/Serial Number similar to the probe callback in an USB-driver?
3. Is this a silly thing to try do, if so why?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the code under http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/bluetooth/?  You may want to examine these drivers to find a similar device or see if any driver currently exists for the chipset vendor.

Comment: Oh, it appears my question is ambigous. @PeterL. I am trying to connect to a remote bluetooth device. Not a bluetooth adapter/controller. So the driver/bluetooth drivers are unfortunately not what I am looking for.

Comment: I understand it's not what you want to hear, but if you can do it in userland, you should do it in userland.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you can say how bluetooth scanning process is organized(sorry about this word, cannot select synonym) in user space, so why wouldn't you try to investigate what is going on during that moment in kernel space? What system-calls were called when you scan the air? What ioctl, what parameters? And so on.
2. Well, actually everything is possible. But as I think it's not good idea to add this functional on USB driver, since it was developed for more common things. As an advice I would try to implement any kernel thread with TRACE EVENTS.

Comment: 1: That is an excellent suggestion, I shall try that once I return from my vacation.

2: Could you elaborate a bit on what you mean here? Why would it be a bad idea to implement an usb-driver like this? Is your advice on trace points simply to enable easier analysis, or is there something  more to it that I'm not picking up?

Comment: I think this is a bad idea because of these reasons:
1. The main purpose of any driver is to insist the hardware work under control of any OS. Just this kind of functionality. Why the other exclusive functionality should be add into driver?Do you know the principle - Keep It Simple? BTW, there might be any problems with supporting such a software.

Comment: About TRACE EVENTS. Yes, I meant exactly what you were saying. It was the first thing that came into my mind.
But I cannot help you much with that, cause didn't have such experience.
Anyway, if you will have any questions, I'll help if I can. I had an expedience of software development in kernel space.